# MongoDB : Mongoclient connection fails after timeout with error No route to host

Tags: mongodb, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

```
client = new MongoClient("mongodb://user:password@192.168.1.12/goplowdb");
client.StartSession();
```

This code is in Xamarin.Forms, MongoDB library version is 2.10.2

The startsession api fails and gives following exception:

```
System.TimeoutException
  Message=A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "Automatic", Type : "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "192.168.1.12:27017" }", EndPoint: "192.168.1.12:27017", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No route to host

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

  at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.ConnectAsync (System.Net.Sockets.Socket socket, System.Net.EndPoint endPoint, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0013f] in <ba66cc1532b240f99569727b03b5b258>:0 
  at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.CreateStreamAsync (System.Net.EndPoint endPoint, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0015b] in <ba66cc1532b240f99569727b03b5b258>:0 
  at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync (System.Threading.CancellationToken
```

1) I have disabled the firewall of my machine(192.168.1.12) and allowed all the incoming connection requests, this code is running on my android mobile phone.

2) I tested using mongo client, mongod server is running and responding on same ip.

3) I tried to connect with and without authentication but still same error.

Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: have you verified connectivity from your device/emulator using the browser?

Comment: Thanks for your direction, i tried to access 192.168.1.12:27017 from Mobile device browser and getting error it cant be reached, my mobile ip is 192.168.1.10, so it seems to be on same modem , same network.

Comment: When I accessed it on my windows 10 browser (same machine 192.168.1.12 then it worked) .Got this --> "It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port".

Comment: are you sure your server can accept requests from external clients?

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks alot for your hint, I got it working. Basically after enabling port forwarding I had to restart the router and my machine, then I was able to access my mongodb server from my mobile device. And my code also worked.